# Error when setting table datasource to a certain class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I'm currently learning how to make multiple cell types for a single tableView and I get an error when I try to set a datasource for the `UITableView` in Swift 4.

I get an error like this below

> Cannot assign value of type 'ProfileViewModel.Type' to type 'UITableViewDataSource?'

The code I get this error message is this one

```
tableView?.dataSource = ProfileViewModel
```

Details about the code is below. This class is out of original `ViewController` class but I declared the class with `UITableViewDataSource`.

```
class ProfileViewModel: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    var items = [ProfileViewModelItem]()

    init(profile: Profile) {
        super.init()
        guard let data = dataFromFile(filename: "ServerData") else {
            return
        }

        let profile = Profile(data: data)

        if let name = profile.fullName, let pictureUrl = profile.pictureUrl {
            let nameAndPictureItem = ProfileViewModelNameAndPictureItem(pictureUrl: pictureUrl, userName: name)
            items.append(nameAndPictureItem)
        }
        if let about = profile.about {
            let aboutItem = ProfileViewModelAboutItem(about: about)
            items.append(aboutItem)
        }
        if let email = profile.email {
            let dobItem = ProfileViewModelEmailItem(email: email)
            items.append(dobItem)
        }
        let attributes = profile.profileAttributes
        if !attributes.isEmpty {
            let attributesItem = ProfileViewModelAttributeItem(attributes: attributes)
            items.append(attributesItem)
        }
        let friends = profile.friends
        if !profile.friends.isEmpty {
            let friendsItem = ProfileViewModeFriendsItem(friends: friends)
            items.append(friendsItem)
        }
    }

}

extension ProfileViewModel {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items[section].rowCount
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // config
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Unrelated, your `init` doesn't quite make sense as you pass it a `Profile`, but you then appear to disregard that parameter. You might want to review that...

Comment: Thank you for your comment Rob! I didn't notice that. I'm gonna fix it. I think I dont need to declare profile after the init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to the class, but you need to refer to an instance of that class. Thus, you need to instantiate your `ProfileViewModel`:

```
class ViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let profile = ...
        profileViewModel = ProfileViewModel(profile: profile)   // it doesn't look like you need this parameter, so remove it if you don't really need it

        tableView?.dataSource = profileViewModel

        ...
    }
}
```

Note, I didn't just do the following directly:

```
tableView?.dataSource = ProfileViewModel(profile: ...)
```

The problem is that the tableView doesn't keep a strong reference to its `dataSource`, and this will be deallocated. You need to keep your own strong reference to it, and then use that reference.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Rob! I didn't know about the reference stuff. I tried your way and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
tableView?.dataSource = ProfileViewModel
```

You are trying to assign a *type* to `tableView.dataSource`. A table view's datasource can't possibly be a *type*, right? It should be an *object* of a type that conforms to `UITableViewDataSource`.

I think you meant

```
tableView?.dataSource = self
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Ooh I see. Since I started studying swift last month, I don't understand the differences between types and objects to be honest but type is like type of object and I passed a type to datasource which is supposed to be an object I guess?